# How to set ffmpeg qscale in C/C++ for image encoding

Tags: c, encoding, ffmpeg

I have a working image encoder in C++ using ffmpeg as the backend. I am taking videos in and  saving frames out as jpeg, but I am having difficulty adjusting the quality of the output jpegs.
Things I have tried:
Setting `AVCodecContext`'s `global_quality` and `compression_level` fields.
I have also tried setting `qscale` with an `AVDictionary` of options, but have been unsuccessful there too.

I know its possible because with the command line I can
`ffmpeg -i INPUT -q:v 2 output_frame_%02d.jpg` and get higher quality images.

Comment: C and C++ are two different things. Do you want C++ solution or do you want a C solution?

Comment: Ffmpeg is a C library so I don't believe there would be a C++ solution for this, only C, right? I just need to know how to get ffmpeg to behave.

Comment: If you're using C++ you can interface with C code seamlessly. If you're using C exclusively then C++ solutions are irrelevant. C libraries are used in other applications too, but we don't talk of Python/C or Node.js/C as if they're one thing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The command line `-q` option effects two things

```
    enc_ctx->flags |= AV_CODEC_FLAG_QSCALE;
    enc_ctx->global_quality = FF_QP2LAMBDA * qscale;
```

where enc_ctx is the AVCodecContext for the output stream and FF_QP2LAMBDA is 118

Comment: You, sir, are the goat. I have been looking for this for FAR too long.

Comment: Looking at ffmpeg's source code, this does not seem to effect the mpegvideo encoders. Do you happen to know how the global quality is set there? I've also tried setting qscale on the encoder context's priv_data and that does not seem to help either.

Comment: I've finally figured it out. Gotta set the AVFrame's quality to the same as the encoder context's global_quality. It's in the ffmpeg.c, but I've only used the libav* stuff.

Answer (score 1):

When you use interface function such as

```
avcodec_decode_video2
avcodec_encode_video2
avcodec_send_frame
avcodec_receive_packet
```

The `flags`and `global_quality` do not work. You should modified **line 3814** at `static int encode_picture(MpegEncContext *s, int picture_number)` in *./libavcodec/mpegvideo_enc.c*:

```
    ...
    if (estimate_qp(s, 0) < 0)
        return -1;
    s->qscale = 5; //modify qscale here
    if (s->qscale < 3 && s->max_qcoeff <= 128 &&
        s->pict_type == AV_PICTURE_TYPE_I &&
        !(s->avctx->flags & AV_CODEC_FLAG_QSCALE))
        s->qscale= 3; //reduce clipping problems
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, setting the global_quality didn't work.

I changed qmin instead of global_quality and it worked.

```cpp
jpegContext->flags |= AV_CODEC_FLAG_QSCALE;
jpegContext->qmin = 3;
```

or change the quality of pFrame

```cpp
jpegContext->flags |= AV_CODEC_FLAG_QSCALE;
pFrame->quality = FF_QP2LAMBDA * qscale;
```

Refer to [this project](https://github.com/developer0hye/Practical-FFmpeg-Examples/blob/main/video2jpgs.cpp#L29-L30) for practical example